# Describe the induced probability $P_X(D)$ on the space $\mathbb{D}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ of the random variable $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

I know that $P_X(D)$ is determined if I find $P_X(\{d_i\})$ for each $d_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. So $P_X(\{0\})=P[X^{-1}(\{0\})]=\{\text{
the cards that are neither ace nor king nor queen nor jack} \}$, but for example $P_X(\{0\})$ is difficult to describe, is there an easier way to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you agree $P_X(1),P_X(2),P_X(3)$ and $P_X(4)$ are easier to calculate? E.g. $P_X(1)$ is given by the number of jacks divided by $52$. Once you have computed these four probabilities, $P_X(0)$ must be one minus their sum, since all the probabilities add to one.

Comment: $P_X(1)=\{j_1,j_2,j_3,j_4\}$ where $j_i$ are jack

Comment: I think you are confused about what $P_X(1)$ means. Recall that $P_X(1)=P(X^{-1}(\{1\}))$. What you have written in your last comment just the set $X^{-1}(\{1\})$, but you need $P$ of that set. What is the probability of the set {♠J, ♡J, ♣J, ♢J} ?

Comment: I already understand friend, that's $4/52=1/13$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2920809.

Answer (score 0):

$P_X(4)=P\{\mathrm A\heartsuit, \mathrm A\diamondsuit, \mathrm A\clubsuit, \mathrm A\spadesuit \}\\P_X(3)=P\{\mathrm K\heartsuit, \mathrm K\diamondsuit, \mathrm K\clubsuit, \mathrm K\spadesuit\}\\P_X(2)=P\{\mathrm Q\heartsuit, \mathrm Q\diamondsuit, \mathrm Q\clubsuit, \mathrm Q\spadesuit\}\\P_X(1)=P\{\mathrm J\heartsuit, \mathrm J\diamondsuit, \mathrm J\clubsuit, \mathrm J\spadesuit\}\\P_X(0) ~{= P\{2\heartsuit, 2\diamondsuit, 2\clubsuit, 2\spadesuit, 3\heartsuit, \ldots ,10\spadesuit\}\\=1-P_X(4)-P_X(3)-P_X(2)-P_X(1)}$